# How to select <tr> tags inside of a div with aspecific css attrbute via beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape several columns of text contained in td tags with a common css attribute inside of tr with a common css attribute inside of a table with a specific class inside of a div

For example, this is exactly how the website is structured.

```
<div class="stats-table>
   <table class=stats_table>
      <tbody>
         <tr data-row="0">
            <td data-stat="games">38</td>
            <td data-stat="wins">29</td>
            <td data-stat="draws">6</td>
            <td data-stat="losses">3</td>
            <td data-stat="points">93</td>
         </tr>
         <tr data-row="1">
            <td data-stat="games">38</td>
            <td data-stat="wins">28</td>
            <td data-stat="draws">8</td>
            <td data-stat="losses">2</td>
            <td data-stat="points">92</td>
         </tr>
         .
         .
         .
         <tr data-row="19">
            <td data-stat="games">38</td>
           <td data-stat="wins">5</td>
           <td data-stat="draws">7</td>
           <td data-stat="losses">26</td>
           <td data-stat="points">22</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

I want to get the texts enclosed in the td tags

I have tried solving this problem by writing the code below

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
data = soup.select(".stats_table")
all_data = [l.get_text(strip=True) for l in soup.select(".stats_table:has(> [data-row])")]
print(all_data)
```

But when I try to execute this code, I get an empty list. I need your help on this matter, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why your solution did not work?

`>` is used when the element that you are selecting has the parent that you specified on the left side. But since in your case the parent of the `td` is tbody and not element with class `.stats_table`. So as stated if you specify the parent class in the selector it would work as expected. `tr` tag below is not necessary in the selector.

Also `has` tag means that selector matches element with class `.stats_table` that directly contains an element that has some element with `data-row` attribute in it.

```
soup.select(".stats_table tbody:has(> tr[data-row])")
```

But this won't give you the expected output. To get the expected output follow this below.

##### Solution

I see that you specifically want all the element "that has an attribute `[data-row]` inside the table class `stats-table`".

There are 2 ways in which you can do this.

- Using regex

```
import re

html = '''
<div class="stats-table">
   <table class="stats_table">
      <tbody>
         <tr data-row="0">
            <td data-stat="games">38</td>
            <td data-stat="wins">29</td>
            <td data-stat="draws">6</td>
            <td data-stat="losses">3</td>
            <td data-stat="points">93</td>
         </tr>
         <tr data-row="1">
            <td data-stat="games">38</td>
            <td data-stat="wins">28</td>
            <td data-stat="draws">8</td>
            <td data-stat="losses">2</td>
            <td data-stat="points">92</td>
         </tr>
         <tr data-row="19">
            <td data-stat="games">38</td>
           <td data-stat="wins">5</td>
           <td data-stat="draws">7</td>
           <td data-stat="losses">26</td>
           <td data-stat="points">22</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
datastats = soup.find_all("td", {"data-stat" : re.compile(r".*")})
for stat in datastats:
    print(stat.text)
```

which gives us the expected output

```
[38,29,6,3,93,38,28,8,2,92,38,5,7,26,22]
```

- Using CSS Selector

The below selector means that select all the `td` tags that has an attribute `data-stat` inside the table that has class `stats_table`. You may or may not use `td` beside `[data-stat]` as `("table.stats_table td[data-stat]")`

```
datastats = soup.select("table.stats_table [data-stat]")
for stat in datastats:
    print(stat.text)
```

which gives us the same output

```
[38,29,6,3,93,38,28,8,2,92,38,5,7,26,22]
```

You can find more information on [`CSS_SELECTOR here`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)